# Fill empty rows in Pandas with value below from same column

Tags: python, pandas

I can see countless posts asking on to fill empty rows with the above value or specific values, but none about filling rows with a value of the same column but *below*.

I would like to go from this table:

[image: my_table]

from a table with all lines above 3 filled with 3, and all lines above 2 and below 3 with 2, etc.

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Found it!

df[col] = df[col].bfill() - as simple as that :)

Comment: What should be filled on the last lines if the last line is empty?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Ilya the last line is not empty ;)

Comment: @Saaa So what to fill them with?

Comment: @Ilya well same: every empty row above a row with a value should be replaced with that value

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[8, 2, "", 0],
                   [3, 4, "", 1],
                   [5, 3, "", 0],
                   [2, 3, 10, 4]],
                  columns=list("ABCD"))

df= df.replace(to_replace="", method='bfill').values
print(df)
```